# How to replace a string with constant in apex class?

Tags: apex

In my apex class there is a String as 'India' . I have to replace it by constant. I dont know how to do that.

Please provide answer for this...!!

Comment: It would be easier to help you out if you could add a code sample which explains what you're trying to do..

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could simply create a static final variable.  This is a fairly pretty common way of using Constants in code so that you aren't using magic variables.

```
public class Constants
{
  public static final String DEFAULT_COUNTRY = 'India';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the Salesforce String methods, Not sure what you are wanting to do. replace the String with what.

Putting the code in will also help

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Custom Setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm) with 'India' as value, and call it in your code like:

```
MyCustomSetting__c.IndiaConstant__c
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nebula mentions, a Custom Label would be perfect for this.

You can then easily refer to it like so:

```
$Label.LabelName
```

This is especially helpful if you are creating a multilingual application, as you can store different translations for the same string and have them appear in the user's native language - but even if you don't have that requirement, they are still a great way of storing information that needs to appear in multiple locations.

For more information, see https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cl_about.htm&language=en_US